# Forced update to multiple clients

Tags: .net, installation, .net-4.5, auto-update

We are developing a (WPF) software which runs as a standalone application on a each client, and is connecting to a database server. You can look at it like this: 1 database server = 1 customer = dosens / hundreds of client PCs connecting to this database. Currently we have made an installer using WIX.

Lets take this potential situation into account: we issue a new version of our software, which contains some database schema changes. That will mean that if one client installs new version, and updates database schema, software from all other clients will become non-functional.

So, what are available update options in this scenario? Is there something like a forced update, issued from a single location, to all clients?

Answer (score 0):

We have similar update requirements. When updates to an application are aligned with changes to the database, or a stored procedure, any variance between the changes to the Database or Stored Procedures, and the updated client application could cause an error.

Short of overhauling the database schema, if it is simply a change in an SP, you could version your SP's and only have the new SP called from the updated software.

Because our products are all deployed on a network, we use ClickOnce for our deployment.  We manually run code to check for an update.  For this, we actually read the manifest file. We prefer this method instead of tracking versions on the database, as it doesn't require us to maintain versioning. (That is what ClickOnce is for)

We run the version check on startup. If an update is required, we force the update, and require the user restart the application.

Comment: The problem is that our applications do not stop, they collect the data continuously. So, how do you make sure that all of them are updated at the same time? The way I see it, one client could restart the app, and see an update, and start the update process, while all other clients are still running. I am not sure what advantage you have with ClickOnce, but it would be quite easy to write a check for app update, and if it exists, fire an update process.

Comment: The problem here is #WHEN#: we cannot depend on a clock, since clocks on different PCs will probably not be synchronized. We also cannot depend on the internet access to check for time. It is important to roll an update at the same time on all machines.